# org.jooq.impl.ParserException: Token ')' expected: [1:11] select (@i[*]:=@i+1)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

how to fix this problem?  thanks!

```
ResultQuery<?> query2 = create
                    .parser()
                    .parseResultQuery("select (@i:=@i+1)");
```

Answer (score 1):

jOOQ does not yet support MySQL's SQL variables. The relevant feature request is here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2558

In ordinary jOOQ API usage, you'd be resorting to using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), but there's currently no workaround when using the parser. I've created a feature request to implement such a workaround syntax: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9260 It might look similar to:

```
select /* [jooq field start] */ @i := @i + 1 /* [jooq field stop] */
```

Starting with jOOQ 3.12, jOOQ supports the [procedural languages](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/procedural-statements/) of many RDBMS, including MySQL. You can still not use jOOQ to manipulate variables from within SQL statements, but you can use the [imperative style variable assignment](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/procedural-statements/procedural-variables/) here:

```
i.set(i.plus(1))
```

Note that in many cases, starting with MySQL 8's [window function support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), there is no more need to use this vendor-specific, and not strictly declarative programming style syntax anymore in pure SQL.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i solved it in this way finally!                                                                  
          WindowPartitionByStep<Integer> over = rowNumber().over();
        Field<Long> cast = over.cast(Long.class); `